# How to play video from android cache directory?

Tags: android, android-videoview

In my android application I want to play video from cache directory It is working fine in android 4.1.1 but in android 2.3.3 It shows the message like **"Sorry this video cannot be played"** .  I want play that  video in android video view. How to read the file from cache directory.

Comment: have you tried a different video/encoding?

Comment: E/MediaPlayer(5412): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(5412): Error (1,-2147483648)
 D/VideoView(5412): Error: 1,-2147483648 This is the error i am getting